# How to set author for post AND post attachments

Tags: attachments, post-meta, author

I have multiple author accounts on one of my WordPress installs.  Often I will create a post, and set the author to be a different account.  However, when I upload images into that post, their attachment page lists the author as my account.  How can I set the author for posts, and have it carry over to the media associated with that post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'add_attachment', 'wpse_55801_attachment_author' );

function wpse_55801_attachment_author( $attachment_ID ) 
{
    $attach = get_post( $attachment_ID );
    $parent = get_post( $attach->post_parent );

    $the_post = array();
    $the_post['ID'] = $attachment_ID;
    $the_post['post_author'] = $parent->post_author;

    wp_update_post( $the_post );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this only work for new posts? I added the filter to my `functions.php` but it seems that it won't be applied to existing posts / attachments.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Actually, after adding, it doesn't seem to be working on new posts either.

Comment: @Ryan . Well, I did test before publishing... Re-tested now with WP 3.4 & TwentyEleven 1.4 & Custom Post Type, and another with WP 3.1 & TwentyTen 1.2 & normal Post... Works on both... Can you test in a clean WP install? :::: For updating old posts, couple [one of these solutions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bget_posts+%2Bforeach+%2Bwp_update_post) with my code.

Answer (score 2):

I extended the above solution of @brasofilo to also change the attachment post date to the date of the post parent.

And not only on upload of the attachment, but also when an attachment is edited. You can use the `edit_attachment` filter with the same function for this. However, when you do that, the `wp_update_post` function causes an infinite loop and leads to PHP memory errors, I found out the hard way after a lot of searching. 
A warning for this infinite loop is actually mentioned in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

A solution is to remove the filters, like so:

```
function wpse_55801_attachment_author( $attachment_ID ) {

    remove_filter('add_attachment', 'wpse_55801_attachment_author');
    remove_filter('edit_attachment', 'wpse_55801_attachment_author');

    $attach = get_post( $attachment_ID );
    $parent = get_post( $attach->post_parent );

    $the_post = array();
    $the_post['ID'] = $attachment_ID;
    $the_post['post_author'] = $parent->post_author;
    $the_post['post_date'] = $parent->post_date;

    wp_update_post( $the_post );

    add_filter( 'add_attachment', 'wpse_55801_attachment_author' );
    add_filter( 'edit_attachment', 'wpse_55801_attachment_author' );
}   

add_filter( 'add_attachment', 'wpse_55801_attachment_author' );
add_filter( 'edit_attachment', 'wpse_55801_attachment_author' );
```