# How can i change an image's author?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, attachments

Is there any function to change the image Author(Uploaded By) in WordPress library?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_update_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)

```
$my_post = array(
'ID' => $post_id,
'post_author' => $user_id,
);
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Or change image's author via a function using GravityForms uploader

```
add_action("gform_user_registered", "image_author", 10, 4);
function image_author($user_id, $config, $entry, $user_pass) 
{
$post_id = $entry["post_id"];

$args = array(
'post_parent' => $post_id,
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image'
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
if($attachments) :
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) : setup_postdata($attachment);
       $the_post = array();
       $the_post['ID'] = $attachment->ID;
       $the_post['post_author'] = $user_id;

       wp_update_post( $the_post );

   endforeach;
endif;    

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the screenshot you provided, click on the `Edit more detail`. this will redirect you to attachment's page.

Then, click on the `Screen's options` on the top of screen, and check the `Author` box. A new box will be added to your page.

[image: Screen's option box in edit attachment page]

You can there choose an author for your attachment, and save the page.

If you want to do this programmatically on upload or edit, you can use the `add_attachment` or `edit_attachment` filter as shown in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56233/94498) answer.

Otherwise, to change it manually, you can use the [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) function. A photo is an attachment, therefore a post type, so you can change its author by passing an author to `post_author` argument of this function.