# How can i set media attachments to the author of the post or page for already existed posts with attachments

Tags: post-meta, media, attachments, media-library, author

I have been uploading posts for multiple authors in my site and the attachements (photos) are registered all in my account.

Is there a way to set the attachements to have the author of the post ?

I found this [How to set author for post AND post attachments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55801/how-to-set-author-for-post-and-post-attachments)   but it only works for new posts. Is there a solution for the already published posts?

Comment: how would you handle the situation where an attachment is on multiple posts? What's the problem that doing this solves?

Comment: @TomJNowell hello Tom, thank you for your answer. All attachments are not on multiple posts. Each attachment is only attached to one post.